# Sending push notification to particular user

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hi everyone iam having a problem with my android app development, please help me find the solution
i have an sql database,with php scripts working in server side, iam fetching some details(information of some other users) from the server through my app (returned as JSON array) and iam detailing it in two listviews.
I want to notify all those people who's details are shown in the listviews(using google cloud push notifications).
But is it possible that after displaying the users details in the listviews pass all their id's along with the current user's id back to the server and then use GCM to send push notifications to all these users(who's id are returned to server.
please help me 
or please suggest some other methods for implementing the same

note: since iam using some filters in the app before displaying the users details in the listview (ie iam not displaying details of all the users that i fetched from database) I cannot send push notifications directly to all people,when fetching data from database.

Answer (score 1):

It does not really matter that the info you want to send is in your ListView or not, as long as you know what you want to send out.

There are two options that I can think of for you to send these registration ID's to your PHP server.

1) Use an HTTPUrlConnection to send JSON data containing the IDs.

2) If your GCM server is on a [Cloud Connection Server setup](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html), you can send upstream messages from your Android client device. Refer [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#upstream) for more details.